# Error al leer esp32 "el dispositivo usb no pudo ser reconocido"

Tags: arduino

El día de ayer compré una esp32, la conecte a mi pc y funcionaba normal, pero cuando fui a subirle el código la esp dejó de funcionar, la desconecte y la volví a conectar pero ahora sale un error que dice "no se puede reconocer el dispositivo usb" en todos lo computadores en los que lo conecto, agradecería si alguien me puede ayudar con eso
Quisiera saber si tal vez hize algo mal al momento de conectarla, si es problema de mi pc o si simplemente la esp32 estaba ya dañada
Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!